# How can I replace numeric values by characters in R?

Tags: r

I have a file like this.

```
"1" 10 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
"2" 10 3 6 17 11 15 8 17 14 1 42 21 22 15 9 9 17 12 9 16 4 8 12 29 23 11 0 0 0 0
"3" 10 4 39 39 14 33 16 23 37 21 29 22 46 26 16 26 21 22 21 10 16 3 10 14 20 12 6 0 0 0
"4" 100 18 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 2 8 5 2 1 2 4 9 6 4 3 0 0
.....................
```

What I want to do is, replace the values from column 4 onwards by characters, i.e. if value is between 0 to 10, then it will be replaced by character 'a' and if it is between 10 to 20, it will be replaced by character b and so on.

For example, the output file will be of the form,

```
"1" 10 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a 0 0 a 0 0 0 0 0 a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
.............................
```

How can I do it in R? Is there someway I can automate the assigning of characters because currently I am using two for loops and harcoding the values by the range.

Edit: My approach:

```
> for ( i in 1:nrow(x) )
+     for ( j in j:ncol(x) )
+         {
+             if (x[i,j] < 10 && x[i,j] > 0 )
+                 x[i,j] = a
+             else if ( x[i,j] < 20 && x[i,j] > 10 )
+                 x[i,j] = b
+         }
```

The above is my approach. This is showing an error in conditions, and I know will take a lot of time since it involves usage of two for loops.

Comment: Please provide your data from `dput`output. Besides, what code have you used so far? Did you get any errors? You haven't shown any effort in solving your own problem.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match what you described. Why `4` was replaced by `d` instead of `a`?

Comment: @David, My bad. I have edited it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to create a dummy data set to match against, and then match all non zero values to it (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
matchData <- data.frame(lets = c(0, rep(letters, each = 10)),
                        nums = c(0, seq_len(length(letters)*10)))

df[, -seq_len(3)] <- sapply(df[, -seq_len(3)], function(x) matchData$lets[match(x, matchData$nums)])
df
#   V1  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
# 1  1  10  2  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   a   0   0   a   0   0   0   0   0   a   0
# 2  2  10  3  a  b  b  b  a  b   b   a   e   c   c   b   a   a   b   b   a   b   a   a   b   c
# 3  3  10  4  d  d  b  d  b  c   d   c   c   c   e   c   b   c   c   c   c   a   b   a   a   b
# 4  4 100 18  0  0  0  a  0  0   0   0   0   0   a   0   0   a   0   a   a   a   a   a   a   a
#   V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31
# 1   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2   c   b   0   0   0   0
# 3   b   b   a   0   0   0
# 4   a   a   a   a   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ascii codes and an offset based on your value/10 (without remainder)...

```
mydat = c(10,2,0,19,20,19,0,0)

# Convert a number divided by 10 to its offset (hat tip to MrFlick for `letters`
# this uses the cryptic looking %/% operator for division without remainder

char10 = letters[1+(md %/% 10)] 

# convert zeroes, and if desired replace column 1:4 with original data 
char10[md==0] = 0
```

Output:

```
> char10
[1] "b" "a" "0" "b" "c" "b" "0" "0"
```

Comment: I best you would have an easier time usiing the build in `letters` vector rather than `rawToChar` if you're just suing acsii values. ie, `letters[1]=="a"`, `letters[2]=="b"`, etc... so `asc10 = function(x) { letters[1+(x%/%10)] }` or something like that (didn't test)

Comment: Great idea. I thought there must be a better way. Then I don't need the `strsplit` step either. I'll add a solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will be close, just a quick answer that hopefully helps you along.  You'd have to apply over this method to do it for the entire dataframe.  Also there's coercion that I didn't handle here, so when testing on a single row everything got coerced into a char.

The basic thought is that if you want 1-10 to correspond to "a", 11-20 to correspond to "b", then we can get that by dividing the number by 10, then calling ceiling.  1-10 then maps to 1, 11-20 then maps to 2, and so forth.  letters[1] maps to "a", letters[2] maps to "b", ect so we get the desired functionality.

```
 #everything coerced to char, I know
 testVect<-c("2", 10, 3, 6, 17, 11, 15, 8 ,17, 14, 1, 42, 21, 22, 15, 9, 9, 17, 12, 9, 16, 4, 8, 12 ,29, 23, 11, 0, 0 ,0 ,0)

 testAfter4<-sapply(testVect[4:length(testVect)], 
        function(entry) {
              ifelse(entry==0, 0, letters[ceiling(as.numeric(entry)/10)])
         } )
 #need to cast entry back to numeric as it was coerced to char when initializing testVect

 testVect[4:length(testVect)]<-testAfter4

 testVect
 #[1] "2"  "10" "3"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "e"  "c"  "c"  "b" 
 #[16] "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "b"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "b"  "0"  "0"  "0" 
 #[31] "0"
```

Comment: and reading over the answers, I guess this is just another form of David's answer, just don't need to create the dummy set